# Django look up foreign-key form field (Newbie Question)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

This is a basic question, but for some reason I cannot seem to find a straight answer, neither in the docs, nor in this forum. I am sure there must be a simple answer, but then again, I am new to Django (I know Python and databases pretty well)

Scenario:
2 classes connected with a foreign key: Order --(foreign key)--> Order-approver (approver pk, fullname, title, etc.). Approver to Order is one-to-many relationship

In the order entry form, I want to be able to pick/enter the approver by the *full name* (Django should presumably translate it into the approver id behind the scene).
Ideally, there should be a look up form so I can select an approver by the name from the list

How do I do that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use django model form. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/. with ModelForm, django will automatically generate select form which appropiate with your model
this is my project screenshot and source code for example

screenshot[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtI2v.png

```
class FormDaftarPegawaiBaru (forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Pegawai
    fields = '__all__'
    labels = {'nip': '', 'nama': '', 'tempatLahir': '',
              'tanggalLahir': '', 'stasiunKerja': 'Stasiun Kerja'}
    widgets = {
        'nip': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'NIP'}),
        'nama': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Nama Lengkap'}),
        'tempatLahir': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Tempat Lahir'}),
        'tanggalLahir': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Tanggal Lahir (10/28/2000)'}),
        'stasiunKerja': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', }),
    }
```

and these are model

```
class Stasiun (models.Model):
    nama = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    alamat = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    telepon = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=80)
    kepalaStasiun = models.OneToOneField(
        'Pegawai',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True, )


class Pegawai (models.Model):
    nip = models.CharField(max_length=18, primary_key=True)
    nama = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    tempatLahir = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    tanggalLahir = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    stasiunKerja = models.ForeignKey(
        Stasiun,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,)
```